# CheckBox event listener from setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

So I have a listview that I want to add checkboxes to.

```
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listItems);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

This works and the checkboxes show up. Then I have my `setOnItemClickListener()` for my listview because the user needs to select an item, then the next acitivty will be launched

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
        {
            Intent components = new Intent();

            components.setClass(context, ComponentsActivity.class);
            components.putExtra("studyID", studyID);
            components.putExtra("studyName", studyName);

            startActivity(components);
        }
});
```

However, I want to add a checkbox so that the user can tick that item in the listview to perform other actions. The problem is I can't differentiate the events. When I click on the checkbox, it gets checked but then the list item also gets selected and the new activity starts. I only want the checkbox to be affected when they click on it, not have it launch the new acitivty. I know you can also just create your own adapter but why bother if I can make a checkbox in 2 lines of code. Any suggestions? I just want to be able to check the textbox and get the id of the checked items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never managed to find anything for what I was looking for so I bit the bullet and decided to learn how to make my own custom adapter class. Here is my code if anybody ever runs into this problem. This adapter class is for a listview with text(TextView) and a checkbox.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

ArrayList<String> studies;
Context context;
LayoutInflater myInflater;
ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> arr, Context c)
{
    studies = arr;
    context = c;
    myInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    for(int i = 0; i < studies.size(); ++i)
    {
        positionArray.add(false);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return studies.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return studies.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

public void remove(int i)
{
    this.studies.remove(i);
    this.positionArray.remove(i);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    final int pos = position;
    Holder holder = null;

    //Create the views and populate it with an element from teh array
    if(view == null)
        view = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout, viewGroup, false);//made my own layout for each listview 'cell'

    holder = new Holder();

    TextView study = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.adapterTextView);
    holder.ckbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.adapterCheckBox);

    holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    study.setText(studies.get(position));

    holder.ckbox.setFocusable(false);
    //Since this method gets called whenever we scroll(view recycling), we have to re-check the checkboxes
    holder.ckbox.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));

    holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            //checkBoxArray[pos].setChecked(isChecked);
            positionArray.set(pos, isChecked);
        }
    });


    return view;
}

static class Holder
{
    CheckBox ckbox;
}
```

}